# Trying to store randomly generated floating point numbers in an array.But cann't understand why the array is taking Garbage value

Tags: c, if-statement

**Random No is Generated correctly but when I'm storing it to an array sometimes it accepting garbage value**

```
void main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 0, i = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand();
    /*Generating Random Number in Floating Point. For calculating Dimension of Rectangle*/
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    float a = 5.0, s[20], sum = 0, x_rand;
    for (i=0; i<20; i++)
    {

        x_rand = (((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)) * a) + sum;
        sum += 1.53;
        //s[i] = x_rand;
        if(i != 0)
        {
           if(x_rand>s[i-1])
                s[i] = x_rand;
        }
        else
        {
            s[i] = x_rand;
        }
        printf("%f\n", x_rand);
    }
    printf("--------------------------\n");
    for(i =0 ; i<20; i++)
        printf("%.5f\n",s[i]);
}
```

[Output of The Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOgkk.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I don't think the `else` is attached to the `if` you think it is. Use braces.

Comment: Missing brackets at the first if : `if (i !=0){/*what you wanna do*/}`

Comment: Okay now what you can see is that there's only 1 else statement. The second if doesn't have one. Therefore in the case where`x_rand > s[i-1]` is False, s[i] won't be initialized.. Here's your problem

Answer (score 1):

In your code, in case of `i` is `0`, `s[i]` remains uninitialized.

Use better indentation. Your code essentially is the same as

```
   if(i != 0)
   {
        if(x_rand>s[i-1])
         {
            s[i] = x_rand;
         }
         else
         {
            s[i] = x_rand;
         }
     }
     //where is else????
```

Related, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.8.4.1

> An `else` is associated with the lexically nearest preceding `if` that is allowed by the
>   syntax.

Comment: I think what he wanted to do is
`if(i != 0){ if(x_rand>[s[i-1]){s[i] = x_rand;} } else {s[i]=x_rand;}`

Comment: for (i=0; i<20; i++)
    {

        x_rand = (((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)) * a) + sum;
        sum += 1.53;
        //s[i] = x_rand;
        if(i != 0)
        {
           if(x_rand>s[i-1])
                s[i] = x_rand;
        }
        else
        {
            s[i] = x_rand;
        }
        printf("%f\n", x_rand);
    }

still it is not working.

Comment: @sosad how so??

Comment: @ValentinO. that way, some `i` indexes will also be uninitialized, don;t you think?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I wrote what I thought he wanted to do, I do not say that it is correct ^^ he should have 2 else statements (as you said in your answer), the second putting default value in the array, or he can make another for loop before this to init all array values to 0, as an example